# AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed not found in Metabase.xml IIS 6.1 Server

Tags: iis, asp-classic, webserver, metabase

I'm running IIS 6.1 and I am attempting to upload a file through the browser. I'm running into issues when I upload large files. After doing some digging around, I know I have to edit the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed parameter in the metabase.xml file, however that parameter is not set to begin with.

When I attempt to upload a file, I get the following erorr:

```
request object error asp 0104 : 800004005
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use adsutil.vbs to set the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed parameter from a command prompt:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/ASPMaxRequestEntityAllowed 2048000
```

sets the value to 2MB

adsutil.vbs is located in C:\inetpub\adminscripts

Be sure to give the account running the Application Pool write permissions on the directory you're trying to write to. If I remember correctly, the default AppPool account in IIS6 is `NETWORK SERVICE`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. That did the trick, but now I'm getting a 800a0046 Permission denied error

Comment: You need to give the account write permission on the directory you uplaod to... updated answer

Comment: Changing the directory permissions did the trick. Thanks so much for your help!